# what to use besides OnCurrentChanged since it is not firing WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a combobox with 2 date pickers on my main xaml file

```
<ComboBox Margin="5" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90"
                      x:Name="datOpt"
                      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=dateOptObj.dates}"
                      Background="{x:Null}" />
        <DatePicker Padding="5,5,5,5"
                    Text="{Binding Path=dateOptObj.openDate, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <TextBlock  Padding="5,5,5,5" Text=" to "/>
        <DatePicker Padding="5,5,5,5" 
                    Text="{Binding Path=dateOptObj.closeDate, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

in the viewmodel I create an instance like this

```
public mdDateOptions dateOptObj { get; set; }

        public vwMain()
        {
        try
        {
            // Initialize the panel switches
            dateOptObj = new mdDateOptions();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

the class of mdDateOptions is as follows

```
class mdDateOptions : vwBase
{

    private DateTime _openDate;
    public DateTime openDate
    {
        get
        {
            return _openDate;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_openDate != value)
            {
                _openDate = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("openDate");
            }
        }
    }

    private DateTime _closeDate;
    public DateTime closeDate
    {
        get
        {
            return _closeDate;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_closeDate != value)
            {
                _closeDate = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("closeDate");
            }
        }
    }

    private DateTime _openDatePrevious;
    public DateTime openDatePrevious
    {
        get
        {
            return _openDatePrevious;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_openDatePrevious != value)
            {
                _openDatePrevious = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("openDatePrevious");
            }
        }
    }

    private DateTime _closeDatePrevious;
    public DateTime closeDatePrevious
    {
        get
        {
            return _closeDatePrevious;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_closeDatePrevious != value)
            {
                _closeDatePrevious = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("closeDatePrevious");
            }
        }
    }

    private ICollectionView _datOpts;
    public ObservableCollection<string> dates { get; private set; }
    public ICollectionView datesView
    {
        get
        {
            return _datOpts;
        }
    }
    public mdDateOptions()
    { 

        dates = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        dates.Add("Rolling Year");
        dates.Add("Year to Date");
        dates.Add("Last Year");

        _datOpts = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dates);
        _datOpts.CurrentChanged += new EventHandler(OnCurrentChanged);
    }
    public mdDateOptions(Boolean value)
    {
        dates = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        dates.Add("Rolling Year");
        dates.Add("Year to Date");
        dates.Add("Last Year");


        _datOpts = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dates);
        _datOpts.CollectionChanged += this.OnCurrentChanged;

    }
    public void OnCurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string currSel = (string)_datOpts.CurrentItem;
        DateTime p_date = new DateTime();
        p_date = DateTime.Today;

        switch (currSel)
        {
            case "Rolling Year":
                openDate = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1);
                closeDate = DateTime.Today;

                openDatePrevious = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-2);
                closeDatePrevious = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1);

                break;
            case "Year to Date":
                openDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, 1, 1);
                closeDate = DateTime.Today;

                openDatePrevious = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1).Year, 1, 1);
                closeDatePrevious = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1);
                break;
            case "Last Year":
                openDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1).Year, 1, 1);
                closeDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1).Year, 12, 31);

                openDatePrevious = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.AddYears(-2).Year, 1, 1);
                closeDatePrevious = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.AddYears(-2).Year, 12, 31);
                break;
            default:
                MessageBox.Show("Unknown Date Option");
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

When the program first loads it goes into the OncurrentChanged and loads the appropriate dates. But after when i am clicking a button in a userControl on the same main xaml file the dateOptObj is null and when I try to create a new instance of the mdDateOptions it doesnt trigger the onCurrentChanged because nothing has changed! My question how can I get my dateOptObj to contain the proper dates when clicking my button in the userControl on the main xaml file. Thanks in advance!

This is the main Xaml file

```
<Window x:Class="ManagementDashboard.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ManagementDashboard"
    Title="Dashboard Home" Height="768" Width="1024">

<Window.Resources>
    <vm:vwMain x:Key="viewModel" />
</Window.Resources>

<DockPanel x:Name="viewModel"
        DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewModel}}" >
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Padding="5,5,5,5" Text="Date Options: "/>
        <ComboBox Margin="5" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90"
                      x:Name="datOpt"
                      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=dateOptObj.dates}"
                      Background="{x:Null}" />
        <DatePicker Padding="5,5,5,5"
                    SelectedDate="{Binding Path=dateOptObj.openDate, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <TextBlock  Padding="5,5,5,5" Text=" to "/>
        <DatePicker Padding="5,5,5,5" 
                    SelectedDate="{Binding Path=dateOptObj.closeDate, Mode=TwoWay}" />

        <TextBlock Padding="5,5,5,5" Text="Rep Filter: "/>
        <ComboBox Margin="5" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200"
                      x:Name="repOption"
                      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                        DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewModel}}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=reps}"
                      DisplayMemberPath="AEname" />
        <!--Background="{x:Null}" />-->


        <Button Margin="5" Width="100" Height="20" Content="Reset Dates" Command="{Binding Path=Refill}" />

    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
        <Button Margin="5" Width="100" Height="20" Content="Exit" Command="{Binding Path=ExitCommand}" />
    </StackPanel>

    <vm:StatPanel  DockPanel.Dock="Right" Loaded="StatPanel_Loaded" />

    <vm:MainBody DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewModel}}"/>

</DockPanel>
```

this is the code behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    vwMain _viewModel;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Initialize the view Model
        _viewModel = (vwMain)this.FindResource("viewModel");
    }

    private void StatPanel_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

this is the part of the XAML of the UserControl

```
<Expander   Header="New Account Stats" IsExpanded="{Binding Path=newAcctPanel, Mode=TwoWay}" ExpandDirection="Down">
            <DataGrid 
                x:Name="m_DataGrid"
                ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                DataContext="{Binding Path=dashNewAcct.newAcctStats}"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                ColumnWidth="Auto">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <!--<DataGridTextColumn Header="Sector"  
                                             Binding="{Binding Path=sector}" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Security"  
                                             Binding="{Binding Path=totalSecurities}" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="CD"  
                                             Binding="{Binding Path=totalCD}" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="LPC"  
                                             Binding="{Binding Path=totalLPC}" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="BSMS" 
                                             Binding="{Binding Path=totalBSMS, StringFormat='{}{0}'}" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Totals"  
                                             Binding="{Binding Path=total, StringFormat='{}{0}'}" />-->
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>Sector</DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Content="{Binding Path=sector}"></Button>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Security">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Name="Security" Content="{Binding Path=totalSecurities}" Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewModel}, Path=filterGridCommand}">
                                    <Button.CommandParameter>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PassThroughConverter}">
                                            <Binding Path="sector"/>
                                            <Binding ElementName="Security" Path="Name"/>
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </Button.CommandParameter>

                                </Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>CD</DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Name="CD" Content="{Binding Path=totalCD}" Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewModel}, Path=filterGridCommand}">
                                    <Button.CommandParameter>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PassThroughConverter}">
                                            <Binding Path="sector"/>
                                            <Binding ElementName="CD" Path="Name"/>
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </Button.CommandParameter>
                                </Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>LPC</DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Name="LPC" Content="{Binding Path=totalLPC}" Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewModel}, Path=filterGridCommand}">
                                    <Button.CommandParameter>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PassThroughConverter}">
                                            <Binding Path="sector"/>
                                            <Binding ElementName="LPC" Path="Name" />
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </Button.CommandParameter>
                                </Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>BSMS</DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Name="BSMS" Content="{Binding Path=totalBSMS}" Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewModel}, Path=filterGridCommand}">
                                    <Button.CommandParameter>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PassThroughConverter}">
                                            <Binding Path="sector"/>
                                            <Binding ElementName="BSMS" Path="Name" />
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </Button.CommandParameter>
                                </Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>Totals</DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Content="{Binding Path=total}"></Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Expander>
```

Comment: Slightly unconventional binding setup, but from what I can see there isn't anything obviously wrong. You mention that the problem seems to be that clicking a button causes your datacontext's dateOptObj to be nulled. Please post the XAML and any code-behind or related commands you have hooked to that button, as I don't believe the problem lies in what you've posted.

Comment: Steve I have added the XAML and the code behind

Answer (score 0):

`OnCurrentChanged` fires properly, your Bindings are wrong. Bind the `DateTime` properties to `SelectedDate` not `Text`.

```
<DatePicker Padding="5,5,5,5"
            SelectedDate="{Binding Path=dateOptObj.openDate, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<DatePicker Padding="5,5,5,5" 
            SelectedDate="{Binding Path=dateOptObj.closeDate, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: This is probably not a problem of the posted code, because I've tried your code and it was working so far, except the bindings.

Comment: yea i really dont know what else to try